# What's the difference between super() and Parent class name?

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization, super, method-resolution-order

Is there a difference between using `super()` and using the parent class name directly? For example:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print("In parent")
        self.__a=10

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()     # using super()
        Parent.__init__(self)  # using Parent class name

c=Child()
```

Is there internally a difference between `super().__init__()` and `Parent.__init__(self)`?

Comment: `super()` resolves the call using the **MRO**...

Comment: Only different if your subclass has multiple superclasses, or if you might at some point change your subclass to inherit from a different superclass. Btw, "parent class" is not usual terminology for inheritance.

Comment: @khelwood: strictly speaking that is not true: if you subclass a class that has multiple inheritance, your `super()` can in fact delegate to a slibing, not a parent. It simply returns the next in line of the `__mro__`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between super() and calling superclass directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639788/difference-between-super-and-calling-superclass-directly)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not in **this case**. But **in general**, and especially when you use *multiple inheritance*, **`super()` delegates to the next object in the *Method Resolution Order (MRO)*** as is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

> **`super([type[, object-or-type]])`**
>
> Return a **proxy object** that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
>   that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that
>   used by `getattr()` except that the type itself is skipped.
>
> The **`__mro__` attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order** used by both `getattr()` and `super()`. The attribute
>   is dynamic and can change whenever the inheritance hierarchy is
>   updated.
>
> (...)

(copied, boldface added)

Say for instance you define classes like (borrowed from [this question, where the MRO is discussed in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41877220/67579)):

```
class F:
    def __init__(self):
        print('F%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__()

class G: 
    def __init__(self):
        print('G%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__() 

class H: 
    def __init__(self):
        print('H%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__()

class E(G,H):
    def __init__(self):
        print('E%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__()

class D(E,F): 
    def __init__(self):
        print('D%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__() 

class C(E,G): 
    def __init__(self):
        print('C%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__()

class B(C,H): 
    def __init__(self):
        print('B%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__()

class A(D,B,E): 
    def __init__(self):
        print('A%s'%super().__init__)
        super().__init__()
```

Then the `__mro__` of `A` is:

```
A.__mro__ == (A,D,B,C,E,G,H,F,object)
```

Now if we call `A()`, it prints:

```
A<bound method D.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>>
D<bound method B.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>>
B<bound method C.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>>
C<bound method E.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>>
E<bound method G.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>>
G<bound method H.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>>
H<bound method F.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>>
F<method-wrapper '__init__' of A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>
<__main__.A object at 0x7efefd8645c0>
```

so it means that **in the context of `A`** and when trying **to obtain `__init__`** that:

- `super().__init__` of `A` is `D.__init__`;
- **`super().__init__` of `D` is `B.__init__`**;
- `super().__init__` of `B` is `C.__init__`;
- `super().__init__` of `C` is `E.__init__`;
- `super().__init__` of `E` is `G.__init__`;
- `super().__init__` of `G` is `H.__init__`;
- `super().__init__` of `H` is `F.__init__`; and
- `super().__init__` of `F` is `object.__init__`.

Note thus that `super()` does **not per se delegates to a parent**. For instance the `super()` of `D` is `B` and `B` is not a superclass of `D`, so it really **depends on the type of the object** (not on the class).

Now in case of `D`, the `__mro__` is:

```
D.__mro__ = (D,E,G,H,F,object)
```

If we construct a `D` however we get:

```
D<bound method E.__init__ of <__main__.D object at 0x7efefd864630>>
E<bound method G.__init__ of <__main__.D object at 0x7efefd864630>>
G<bound method H.__init__ of <__main__.D object at 0x7efefd864630>>
H<bound method F.__init__ of <__main__.D object at 0x7efefd864630>>
F<method-wrapper '__init__' of D object at 0x7efefd864630>
```

So **in the context of `D`** it holds that:

- **`super().__init__` of `D` is `E.__init__`**;
- `super().__init__` of `E` is `G.__init__`;
- `super().__init__` of `G` is `H.__init__`;
- `super().__init__` of `H` is `F.__init__`; and
- `super().__init__` of `F` is `object.__init__`.

So here **the `super()` of `D` leads to `E` (for `__init__`)** which is **not the same in the context of `A`**.

Comment: I think you missed the most important part there by ending your last sentence too soon:  `super()` in `A` will delegate to `D` and the `super()` call in `D` will delegate to `B` whereas if you started with a `D` instance its `super()` call would go to `E`.

Comment: Yes, your edit crossed with my comment. Much better though I still think it would be useful to show that for a direct D instance `super()` goes somewhere different.

Answer (score 7):

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Perceive you don't pass the "self" - it is inserted automatically.

`super()` was first designed in Python 2 to allow classes to be reused as mixins in a class hierarchy in a way that their immediate superclass may change:

Let's supose at some point in time your code is like:

```
class A: pass
class B(A): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          ...
          # Fixed call to A
          A.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          ...
          # Fixed call to A
          A.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class D(C, B): 
    pass
```

At this point, correct OOP code should execute `C.__init__`   which should chain the call to `B.__init__`: but when the superclass name is hardcoded that does not happen - `A`'s `__init__` would always come next. 
And if you hardcode `B.__init__` in `C`, you would prevent `C` from working without `B`, defeating the purpose of multiple inheritance.

When you use `super()` instead, Python's perform the method search for the next parent class looking on the class's `__mro__` attribute (mro = method resolution order. `__mro__` is a concrete attribute attached to each Python class).  - So, if at some point in time class `D` above no longer inherits from `B`, the calls to `super().__init__`  in `C` will be automatically re-routed straight to `A`.

It is also worth noting that in Python 3 the parameterless form of `super` was introduced to ease its use - prior to that, one had to hardcode a reference to the own class and also insert `self` in the parameters. This form is one of the few exceptions in Python that is hardcoded in the compiler itself - it do change things internally on methods when `super` (or `__class__`) is seen inside a method body (namely, it creates a `__class__` variable pointing to the class itself which the `super` call uses)