# When to use self, super() and class name while calling super method from child?

Tags: python

`super().method()` and `ClassName.method()` do the same thing but when to use `super().method()` vs `self.method()`?

Based on my understanding, one will use `super().method()` when super method is called **from the same method** whereas will use `self.method()` when calling **from other methods** of the child class.

```py
class Animal():
    def run(self):
        print('running')

    def walk(self):
        print('walking')


class Cat(Animal):
    def run(self):
        super().run()

    def walk_fast(self):
        self.walk()       ---> super().walk() also works but any reason using one over the other ?

c = Cat()
c.run()
c.walk_fast()
```

Comment: if you create method `walk()` in `Cat()` then `self.walk()` will still work correctly. if you remove `walk()` from `Animal()` and keep `walk()` in `Cat()` then `self.walk()` will still work correctly.

Comment: [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python) It lets you access class methods that you've shadowed by redefining names.

Comment: All three `ClassName.method` `super().method` and `self().method` are all different from each other @KetanPatel, Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

`super()` references the parent class while `self.method()` executes the method of the class itself.

Since `Cat` inherits from `Animal`, `c.run()` should print `running`.

However, you do not have to redefine the `run()` function in `Cat` because it already inherits the methods from `Animal`. `c.run()` will already print `running`.

Similarly, `self.walk()` is working your function because it is defined in `Animal`, and `Cat` inherits from `Animal`.

`super()` is usually used with `__init__()`, where you want to initialize the parent class's properties in the child class. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) for more details.

Comment: Thanks gkhnavarro.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should make it clear for you

```
class Animal():
    def run(self):
        print('running')

    def walk(self):
        print('Animal is walking')

    #Static method called walk
    @staticmethod
    def static_walk():
        print('Animal is walking in static')

class Cat(Animal):

    def run(self):
        super().run()

    def walk(self):
        print('Cat is walking')

    def walk_fast(self):
        #This calls walk of Animal
        super().walk()

        #This calls walk of Cat
        self.walk()

        #This calls static method walk of Animal
        Animal.static_walk()
```

The output will be

```
running
Animal is walking
Cat is walking
Animal is walking in static
```

- `Cat().walk_fast()`, `super().walk()` is going to call the `walk` of `Animal` class, hence you see `Animal is walking`.
- Doing `super().method()` will call the method of the superclass, if it is implemented in the superclass,
- `self.walk()` is going to call the `walk` of `Cat` class, hence you see `Cat is walking`
- `self.method()` calls the method of the class itself
- Doing `ClassMethod.method()` will call the `static` method of the class, so `super().method()` and `ClassName.method()` are not the same!
- `Animal.static_walk()` is going to call the static method of `Animal` class, hence you see `Animal is walking in static`

Comment: Great! Glad to help :) If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer @KetanPatel :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `super()` is a  reference to the parent class.  It is usually used with descriptors and magic methods such as `__init__`.  It allows you to call a method directly from the parent class without having to define the parent classes name.  It also allows you to move multiple inheritance levels following the `mro`

There is no direct difference from using self except when there is a conflict with the name of the method i.e

```
class Animal():
    def run(self):
        print('running')

    def walk_fast(self):
        print('walking')


class Cat(Animal):
    def run(self):
        super().run()

    def walk_fast(self):
        super(Cat).walk_fast()
        print('After walking')

c = Cat()
c.run()
c.walk_fast()
```

Comment: This is not true, `super()` does not necessarily delegate to parent class. it could also be a sibling class, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42413830/11887333)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the name explained everything, if you write the code this way you can see the difference

```
class Animal:
    def run(self):
        print('running')

    def walk(self):
        print('walking')


class Cat(Animal):
    def run(self):
        # override to make a difference between self.run() and super().run()
        print('running like a cat')

    def run_super(self):
        super().run()

    def run_self(self):
        self.run()


c = Cat()
c.run() # running like a cat
c.run_super() #running
c.run_self() # running like a cat
c.walk() # Cat don't have walk, call go to Animal (e.g. super())
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for clarifying it. I got the purpose of super now.