# Grandchild inheriting from Parent class - Python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am learning all about Python classes and I have a lot of ground to cover.
I came across an example that got me a bit confused.

These are the parent classes

```
Class X
Class Y
Class Z
```

Child classes are:

```
Class A (X,Y)
Class B (Y,Z)
```

Grandchild class is:

```
Class M (A,B,Z)
```

Doesn't `Class M` inherit `Class Z` through inheriting from `Class B` or what would the reason be for this type of structure? `Class M` would just ignore the second time `Class Z` is inherited wouldn't it be, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that this is redundant. Where did you see this example? I suspect that it is just contrived because I doubt you would do this in any real scenario.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This is a very real concern, and in part is why Java did not include multiple inheritance in its object model at all. Python handles it differently.

Comment: @chepner ooo...I know a little about how C++ implements multiple inheritance and the dangers that led Java to avoid the issue. I guess I need to learn about Python's implementation.

Comment: I edited the last question to make a bit more sense. I knew it wouldn't create duplicates but didn't understand the redundancy. it could just be a contrived example as @Code-Apprentice mentioned. Found the example on programmiz.com under the Python Class tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Class M would just inherit the Class Z attributes *twice* (redundant) wouldn't it be, or am I missing something?

No, there are no "duplicated" attributes, Python performs a **linearization** they can the *Method Resolution Order (MRO)* as is, for instance, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41877220/67579). You are however correct that here adding `Z` to the list does not change anything.

They first construct MRO's for the parents, so:

```
MRO(X) = (X,object)
MRO(Y) = (Y,object)
MRO(Z) = (Z,object)

MRO(A) = (A,X,Y,object)
MRO(B) = (B,Y,Z,object)
```

and then they construct an MRO for `M` by merging:

```
MRO(M) = (M,)+merge((A,X,Y,object),(B,Y,Z,object),(Z,object))
       = (M,A,X,B,Y,Z,object)
```

Now each time you call a method, Python will first check if the attribute is **in the internal dictionary `self.__dict__` of that object)**. If not, Python will **walk throught the MRO** and attempt to find an attribute with that name. From the moment it finds one, it will stop searching.

Finally `super()` is a proxy-object that does the same resolution, but starts in the MRO at the stage of the class. So in this case if you have:

```
class B:

    def foo():
        super().bar()
```

and you construct an object `m = M()` and call `m.foo()` then - given the `foo()` of `B` is called, `super().bar` will first attempt to find a `bar` in `Y`, if that fails, it will look for a `bar` in `Z` and finally in `object`.

Attributes are **not** inherited twice. If you add an attribute like:

```
self.qux = 1425
```

then it is simply added to the internal `self.__dict__` dictionary of that object.

Stating `Z` explicitly however can be beneficial: if the designer of `B` is not sure whether `Z` is a real requirement. In that case you know for sure that `Z` will still be in the MRO if `B` is altered.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what @Willem has mentioned, I would like to add that, you are talking about multiple inheritance problem. For python, object instantiation is a bit different compared other languages like Java. Here, object instatiation is divided into two parts :- Object creation(using `__new__` method) and object initialization(using `__init__` method). Moreover, it's not necessary that child class will always have parent class's attributes. Child class get parent class's attribute, only if parent class constructor is invoked from child class(explicitly).

```
>>> class A(object): 
      def __init__(self): 
         self.a = 23
>>> class B(A): 
      def __init__(self): 
         self.b = 33
>>> class C(A): 
      def __init__(self): 
         self.c = 44 
         super(C, self).__init__()
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> c = C()
>>> print (a.a) 23
>>> print (b.a) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> print (c.a) 23
```

In the above code snipped, B is not invoking A's `__init__` method and so, it doesn't have a as member variable, despite the fact that it's inheriting from A class. Same thing is not the case for language like Java, where there's a fixed template of attributes, that a class will have. This's how python is different from other languages.

Attributes that an object have, are stored in `__dict__` member of object and it's `__getattribute__` magic method in object class, which implements attribute lookup according to **mro**  specified by willem. You can use **vars()** and **dir()** method for introspection of instance.